# What is the smartest data structure to use when doing several lookups and insertions, but no deletes?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I will never be deleting from this data structure, but will be doing a huge number of lookups and insertions (~a trillion lookups and insertions).  What is the best data structure for handling this?

Red-black and AVL trees seem decent, but are there any better suited for this situation?

Comment: a trillion ? really? over what time span? is this in-memory or do you need to page to disk (or even across a machine cluster)? (I also like how the title calls a trillion "several"...)

Comment: A trillion lookups and a trillion insertions? A trillion in total? The latter could be interpreted as "a trillion of operations, where 99.999% will be lookups".

Comment: Also, another very important question. Are lookups concurrent? Are insertions concurrent? (For example, for concurrent lookups, a Splay tree would be a particularly bad idea). Or are you really going to burden a *single* core performing all those operations sequentially?

Answer (score 5):

A hash table would seem to be ideal if you are only doing insertions and lookup by exact key.

Try [Splay trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) if you are doing insertions, and find/find-next on ordered keys.

I assume that most of your operations are going to be lookups, or you're going to need one heap of a lot of memory.

Comment: Size the hash table accordingly up-front to avoid re-hashing. You are not going to have a trillion insertions, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a red-black tree or a hash table. 
Operations on a red-black is O(log2(n)).
If implementet right the hash can have a O(1 + k/n). If implementet wrong it can be as bad as o(k). If what you are trying to do is just to make it as fast as possible, I would go with hash and do the extra work. Otherwise I would go with red-black. It is fairly simple and you know your running time.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the queries are successful (i.e., to elements that are actually stored in the table), then hashing is probably best, and you could experiment with various types of collision resolution, such as cuckoo hashing, which provides worst-case performance guarantees on lookups (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

If some queries are in between the stored keys, I would use van Emde Boas trees, y-fast trees, or fusion trees, which offer better performance than binary search trees (see http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring10/scribe/lec09.pdf and http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring10/scribe/lec10.pdf).